# Apply bitwise operator to values of array

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

What would be the best way to apply the bitwise OR operator (or any operator I suppose) to an array of values in javascript?

```
var array = [1, 5, 18, 4];
// evaluate 1 | 5 | 18 | 4
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and pass *0* as the initial value and logical or each value

```js
var array = [1, 5, 18, 4];

var result = array.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a | b;
}, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Because `a` is an array. And you do `[] | 1, [1] | 5, [1, 5] | 18` and so on. You do Bitwise OR as `[] | integer` which is not what he's asking

Comment: Just updated it to use an initial value to avoid this.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass 0 as the initial value when using OR | ?

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a | b, 0);
```